# Either use the latter file as your input or reorder the --proto_path so that the former file's location comes first

Tags: java, gradle, build, dependencies, protocol-buffers

Getting the error message as below for the scenario, when duplicate proto files are found in proto dependencies during gradle build operation.

```
Either use the latter file as your input or reorder the --proto_path so that the former file's location comes first.
```

We are trying to import two different dependencies as below, but the first one repo has the same proto file as the latter one due to which we are seeing this error and we can't delete either of them due to dependency requirements.

```
github.com/<repo_name>/protoFolder/src/main/proto/abc.proto 

github.com/<repo_name>/src/main/proto/xyz.proto // this proto file is present in the above repository
```

My question is : Is it possible to import that specific proto file only(which has been declared in import) instead of cloning every proto files from other repository?

I am new with protobufs, can anyone please advice or suggest, is there any way we can prevent this issue ?

Comment: having the same issue when using gradle plugin "protobuf-gradle-plugin"
somehow if I'm inheriting zips I end up having this issue

Answer (score -1):

The --proto_path flag is used to specify the directories in which to search for imported .proto files. When you import a .proto file in another .proto file, you need to specify the path to the file using the import statement. For example:

Comment: Your answer seems to be missing a piece, could you edit your answer to add that bit?

Comment: I think you pressed submit to fast